# Visual Studio Code - Remove blank lines from code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code as my preferred text editor and I have ran into a problem with regards to the formatting.  I have copied code from one file and pasted into another, however when I have pasted the code VSC has placed a blank line between every line with code.

It is quite a big file so I am hoping there is a way to identify all the blank lines at once and remove them?

This is how I want the code to look:

```
<div>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

however, on paste it now looks like this:

```
<div>

  <h1></h1>

  <p></p>

</div>
```

I have looked online but have been unable to find any direct answer to this :(

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Follow the steps

1. In windows, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (quick replace).
2. Click "Use Regular Expressions".
3. In Find specify `^$\n`.
4. leave Replace as blank
5. Click "Replace All"
   All Blank lines will be deleted.

[image]

NB: leave the replace box as blank

Comment: Find specify "^$\n". It works like a charm!

Comment: I don't know why it does not work after </form> and it leaves 1 blank line.

Comment: @Tanaka pehaps that line after </form> is not blank and has a space, or tab or any other white space char, the difference described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042278/visual-studio-code-remove-blank-lines-from-code/71458963#comment126306279_67601889)

Comment: Ctrl H deleted the line on my Mac

Comment: use command + Option + F on Mac. Or from the header menu Edit -> Replace

Comment: (    $\n) This worked for me. 4 spaces before $

Answer (score 43):

You can use regular expressions.

1. Open your code in Visual Studio Code
2. From Edit Menu, select Replace or use a short cut key (<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> on Windows)
3. In the find box type `^(\s)*$\n`
4. Leave the replace box empty
5. Make sure the *'Use Regular Expression'* is selected
6. Select the 'Replace All' button

[image]

[I referred to this link. It worked for me](https://www.trainingdragon.co.uk/blog/how-to-remove-empty-lines-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: How is this different from the existing answer?

Comment: Wonderful, it helped for Mac : )

Comment: @FloLie If you mean different from `^$\n` then `^$\n` matches only lines that have no other character than the new line character. `^(\s)*$\n` matches also lines that have white space characters [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71458963/1174405)

Comment: `^(\s)*$\n` no results

Comment: @Snowcrash Make sure that you have clicked on regular expression's icon as shown in the image.

Answer (score 13):

Use the following plugin

```
Remove empty lines
v0.0.11
Alexander
```

Then in settings go and change

```
Remove-empty-lines: Allowed Number Of Empty Lines
Number of allowed consecutive empty lines.
Set to 1
```

On Mac

```
Command-Shift-P -> Remove empty lines : in Document
```

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to remove lines that consist of only these characters:

- A space character
- A tab character
- A carriage return character
- A new line character
- A vertical tab character
- A form feed character

Then use as a regular expression:

```
^\s*$\n
```

in the find and replace box <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open it.

[image]

Turn on regular expression mode <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> [image]

Leave replace field empty:
[image]

Replace all occurences with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or by clicking: [image]

The regex pattern `^\s*$\n` does not use capture and group `()` because it is redundant.

- `^` - matches the beginning of the line
- `\s` - matches any white space character
- `*` - quantity operator for `\s` = match zero or more
- `$` - matches end of the line
- `\n` - matches new line character

Comment: It might be helpful to explain how this is different from the previous answer that uses the same regex.

Comment: @DaveNewton Explanation added.

Comment: Thanks; seems like it might have been better expressed as a comment on the previous answer, but whatever.

Comment: @DaveNewton For the verbosity I created a new answer that allowed me to list all white space characters that regex matched as well.

Answer (score 3):

With extession remove-empty-lines in vscode, you can process the entire document or only the part you choose.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.remove-empty-lines

Answer (score 3):

Here are step-by-step instructions to remove those empty lines:

1. Open your code in Visual Studio Code
2. From Edit Menu, select Replace or use a short cut key (command + Option + F on Mac or Ctrl + H on Windows)
3. In the find box type **`^(\s)*$\n`**
4. Leave the replace box empty
5. Make sure the ‘Use Regular Expression’ is selected
6. Select the ‘Replace All’ button

Comment: How to remove all lines but leave one blank

Answer (score 2):

I found this question when searching for a solution. I did not want to use a regular expression and was able to delete empty lines in a file using a different method with multiple cursors.

1. select the empty space resulting in a desired pattern.
   [Example of selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtnzX.png)
2. Use the command "*Select all Occurrences of Find Match*:", `cmd` + `shift` + `L`

You will then have a cursor at each empty line and can delete them.
[image: Cursors on each empty line]

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom right of the screen you should see LF or CRLF

If it is CRLF it will create the blank lines when you paste the code.
Change it to LF and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

a very simple solution for this is
on Windows press `Crtl + F` and then in the first box type `\n\n` and o replace box type `\n` and after this click on replace untill all the result become zero. dont forgot to select regular expression

[image: check this image]