# how to remove lines from a text using regex?

Tags: regex

I have scraped some data but when i wanna import  it into wordpres theres always a like space

i want to import it like this:

[image]

any solutions. please keep in mine im an absolute noobie just wanna know if theres a simple way to remove these lines

Comment: What editor/tool would you be using to clean up the text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code - delete all blank lines - regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350324/visual-studio-code-delete-all-blank-lines-regex)

Answer (score 1):

According to the picture, it seems you're using Notepad++.

This will remove all linebreak that is followed by another linebreak:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?=\R)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R      # any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?=\R)  # positive lookahead, make sure we have another linebreak after
```

Or, if you have installed TextFX plugin

```
TextX  > TextFX Edit > Delete blank lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution which may work for you:

```
Find: ^$
Replace: (empty)
```

This will target all lines having nothing on them except for a newline character.  Then, it replaces them with nothing, effectively removing them.

Comment: Pure poetry :-)